# Tracing Apache Camel route with Jaeger

Tags: kubernetes, apache-camel, opentracing, jaeger

I have developed a Camel route with Spring Boot. Now I want to trace the route using Jaeger. I tried [this example](https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/examples/camel-example-opentracing) to trace the route using `camel-opentracing` component, but I am unable to get the traces to Jaeger.

I can only see it in the console. One thing I am not clear is where to add the Jaeger URL?
Any working example will be helpful.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/opentracing-contrib/java-spring-jaeger I guess setting opentracing.jaeger.udp-sender.host=jaegerhost and opentracing.jaeger.udp-sender.port=portNumber would help

Comment: Debdeep have you tried what @Simon said? Is problem still exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache Camel doesn't provide an implementation of [OpenTracing](https://opentracing.io/), so you have to add also an implementation to your dependencies. For example [Jaeger](https://www.jaegertracing.io/).

**Maven POM:**

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-opentracing-starter</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.opentracing.contrib</groupId>
        <artifactId>opentracing-spring-jaeger-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Also you have to enable OpenTracing for Apache Camel on your Spring Boot application class, see [Spring Boot](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/others/opentracing.html#_spring_boot):

> If you are using Spring Boot then you can add the `camel-opentracing-starter` dependency, and turn on OpenTracing by annotating the main class with `@CamelOpenTracing`.
>
> The Tracer will be implicitly obtained from the camel context’s Registry, or the ServiceLoader, unless a Tracer bean has been defined by the application.

**Spring Boot application class:**

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@CamelOpenTracing
public class CamelApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CamelApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, did you experience with a bug where only the 1st request sent to Camel Servlet can be searched in Jaeger UI? I could see the multiple spans being reported in the Log but none could be found. Thanks

Comment: @EthanNguyen No, I didn't experience such problem. Are your spans all in the same trace or in different traces? In Jaeger UI you can only search for traces and they are shown as a tree with its spans.

Comment: I actually switch to Camel OpenTelemetry instead of Camel OpenTracing to integrate with Dynatrace

Answer (score 1):

What I eventually did is create a JaegerTraces and annotated with Bean